# What is the 'CToWUd' class in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

All the images in emails I get using gmail appear to have a 'class="CToWUd"' added to them.  What does this do and what does 'CToWUd' stand for?

Comment: Did you ever find out?

Comment: Nope!  Still have no idea.